# disable response headers in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, c#-4.0, iis-7.5

**disable response headers and server details in c# web service**s

not able to find out the solution .
please anyone can help how to remove response headers and disable iis details and x-powered-by in C# asp.net[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You achieve this by making use of `web.config` file.

To remove the server use `PreSendRequestHeaders` event and do

```
Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
```

Or change the server name

```
Response.Headers.Set("Server","FooServer");
```

The above will be achieved in the `Global.asax.cs`

The below will remove `X-AspNet-Version`

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
</system.web>
```

To remove `X-Powered-By` use

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Further reading [here](https://ict.ken.be/removing-x-powered-by-aspnet-and-other-version-headers)

Comment: thanks.. not able to execute this one in my app..  Response.Headers.Remove("Server");

Comment: add above attached my snapshots.. error message is : This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.