# How can I remove some items of Response Headers?

Tags: c#, http

[image]

I wrote a simple HTTP Selfhost

just like the image, how can i remove the Date and Server (selfhost)?

What I can find answers are all not selfhost, so I wanna know how to remove them of selfhost?. Thx!

Comment: From the response? If it is on the response, you need to remove it at the source of the response.

Comment: Can you say *why* you want to remove those headers?  They are there to tell the client certain things it probably expects to see.  Removing them might cause other problems.

Comment: You could consult [this] (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varunm/2013/04/23/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers/) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913198/disable-response-headers-in-asp-net) page. Why do you want to remove Content-Length?